# Doxygen Server-Based Search does not produce any result (even a "no results" portion)

Tags: php, doxygen

Nothing is showing up after using a server-based search.

Configuration is set as:

```
SEARCHENGINE            = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH     = YES
EXTERNAL_SEARCH         = NO
```

After pressing enter and searching for a simple term that I know exists in the project, nothing shows up.
I think the keyword "Search Results" should even be at the top too, but the page does not render anything besides the header.

On Doxygen 1.8.15. Any thoughts on why this would be happening or if any one else has ever used the server-based search feature and ran into this issue?

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.15 is a bit older (December 27, 2018), what happens with the current  (1.9.3) version? Did you make the search engine available as described in the documentation?

Comment: Found out the issue was the Apache server is using PHP 7, and the Doxygen generated PHP files are using <script language="php"></script> tags (deprecated in PHP 7) instead of <?php ?>.

Comment: Can you give some more information (which file, source code snippet) about where you found this `<script language="php"></script>`? I cannot find it neither with the 1.9.3 version nor the 1.8.15 version in an, easy, example nor in the source code.

Comment: I just checked the 1.8.13 and 1.8.14 versions of doxygen and here I saw the offending code. In the 1.8.15 version this has been corrected in favor of `<?php` ... `?>` (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/680 : added PHP7 support for the search engine on HTML output. )So are you sure you are running doxygen 1.8.15 and are you sure you don't run with some old files as well? My advise certainly is to update to doxygen 1.9.3

Comment: I also noticed that they added the fix for PHP 7 in 1.8.15. My mistake, I saw that in my generated config file that the version was 1.8.15, but when I ran doxygen -v, I noticed I was on 1.8.5. I'm using an older version because there is a patch to adapt Doxygen to handle verilog files.

Comment: 1.8.5 is very old (August 2013) so I certainly would say update to the current 1.9.3 version and see when necessary you can update the patch to be used there. What is the contents of the patch? What so specif to verilog files compare to standard vhdl file?

Comment: Regarding the PHP7 support we cannot do anything there, do you have the sources of htmlgen.cpp of that version? maybe you could try to patch those or better post process the resulting / offending files.These actions are heavily discouraged though.

Comment: No worries, there are no issues here anymore. I just needed to change the previous script tags to use new php tags, using a simple Python script to edit the generated files. As for Verilog, the syntax differs from VHDL, and vanilla Doxygen did not document any useful information for Verilog files.

Comment: Some issue. Doxygen version is 1.9.5. 
web server is nginx.
Maybe I need to configure my web server ?